# Saturation of a Graded Radical Ideal in $S=k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $I\subset S=k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ be a graded radical ideal different from $\mathfrak{m}=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$. Prove that $I$ is saturated.

To prove that $I$ is saturated it is sufficient to prove that $I=I:\mathfrak{m}$.

$I\subset I:\mathfrak{m}$ obviously. To prove the other inclusion, we consider $f\in I:\mathfrak{m}$. It follows that $fx_{i}\in I$ for all $i=1,...,n.$ Next I need to show that $f\in I$ but here I am confused about how to prove this.

Comment: This is Problem 1.15 in Ene and Herzog, *Gröbner Bases in Commutative Algebra*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I = \sqrt{I}$ is radical, then $I = p_1 \cap ... \cap p_s$ is the intersection of its minimal primes. Since $I$ is graded, its minimal primes are also graded. Moreover $\mathfrak{m}$ is not a minimal prime of $I$, since $p_j \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ for all $j$.

Now, if $f \in I : \mathfrak{m}$ but $f \not \in I$, then $f \not \in p_j$ for some $j$. As you know, $fx_i \in p_j$ for all $i = 1, ..., n$, but $p_j$ is prime, so $x_i \in p_j$ for all $i$, hence $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq p_j \implies \mathfrak{m} = p_j$, contradiction.

Comment: How is it that minimal primes of a graded ring are graded?

Comment: @user118827: This is a standard exercise (one you should try to do!). You may even wish to prove that every associated prime of a graded ring is graded, and are in fact annihilators of homogeneous elements.